# Getting error in Phonegap developer but working fine in browser Onsen Ui Cordova app

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui, phonegap-desktop-app

I have a list of objects in a page.. Clicking on the list item pushes a new page with some parameters passed from parent page. Navigator's var name is navi. $scope.navi.pushPage('somepage.html', {listItem: item}); and navi.pushPage('somepage.html', {listItem: item}); is working fine in browser. But none of the methods working in Phonegap developer app. I'm testing it in an Android phone running Lollipop 5.0.1.

**Here is the error I'm getting by Logcat.**

```
D/CordovaLog( 7652): : Line 0 : 'Attr.ownerElement' is deprecated and has been r
emoved from DOM4 (http://w3.org/tr/dom).
```

**And few seconds later I get this error:**

```
D/CordovaLog( 7652): http://192.168.1.4:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js: Line 4573 :
 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packed apk. Installed in a physical device. Working fine. I think it's Phonegap Beta Desktop Application problem.